# "annals" or "annuals"

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

I was reading a book from Dale Carneige named "The Art Of Public Speaking"(Originally published: 1915). I encountered that word "**annals**" is that exactly same with "**annuals**" or are there tiny differences?

Comment: They are completely different words, though they originated in the same word in Latin. *Annals* is in the [dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/annals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[annals](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annals)** means reports or records, as of a society or club, or of a broad topic: *[Annals of Medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annals_of_Medicine)* (a medical journal) or *annals of history* (a literary term meaning "recorded history"). The etymology shows that it comes from the Latin *annus*, "year," though its usage today is not restricted to things that are published only once a year. The word is always plural.

**[annual](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/annual#Noun)**, as a noun, means a yearly publication (or yearly version of a publication) and also comes from the Latin *annus*. In that sense it seems rather similar to **annals**, at least in the context of the reports of a society/club/etc, but it *does* apply only to things published once annually, as "annals" does not. [Here is a page](https://www.waterstones.com/annuals) showing a publisher's annuals; you can see they are meant for the mass consumer market, unlike the reports or minutes of a society that are published for posterity's sake. This usage appears to be chiefly British; as an American English speaker I have never heard of this usage before now, and when you say "annual" I would first think of the botanical meaning.

Comment: Here is a link to a large UK bookseller and their list of 2021 annuals so it obviously is still current here https://www.waterstones.com/annuals

Comment: @mdewey thanks for that; I don't believe I've ever seen one, or even heard of the term, in America.